# Regex Match Groups with or with out "-"

Tags: regex

I want to match two groups of strings that comes before and after the hyphen. However, in some cases the hyphen can also be missing. So what I want is:

"Hello World - This is a test": group(1) = Hello World, group(2) = This is a test

"Hello World": group(1) = Hello World, group(2) missing

I've tried some variants of the following regex, but it is not working as I wanted.

```
(.*?)(\-.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it ...

```
([\w\s]+)(?:[\s-]?)(.*?)(?:\n|$)
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xKMJjC/5)**

Comment: Great. Can you explain why adding "$" makes the difference? I understand what $ means but don't understand why removing "$" at the end will result in the entire string matched to group 1.

Comment: @Yang `$` just matching a line break (end of line), thus removing it results in a match of entire sting in Group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Something like `([^-]+?)\s*(?:-\s*(.+))?` which optionally matches
a second group started with a hyphen.

```
 ( [^-]+? )                    # (1)
 \s* 
 (?:
      - \s* 
      ( .+ )                        # (2)
 )?
```